# Factorization of polynomials with degree higher than 2

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I need help to factorize $x^4-x^2+16$. I have tried to take $x^4$ as $(x^2)^2$ and factorize it in the typical way of factorizing a quadratic expression but that did not help. Can someone help me to factor this and also introduce me to the procedure that i need to follow to factorize expressions with degree higher than two?

Comment: Google "StackExchange LaTeX guide" to learn how to format equations.

Comment: Just a hint: if you are given something to factorize at classes, the first step is to try guessing the root, using factorization of the last term. It usually works with easy tasks :)

Answer (score 6):

$$x^4-x^2+16$$

$$=[(x^2)^2+2\cdot x^2\cdot 4+4^2]-9x^2$$

$$=(x^2+4)^2-(3x)^2$$

$$=(x^2+4-3x)(x^2+4+3x)$$

by using $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: So is the middle term in the brackets 2*x^2*4 because the exponents in the original equation are 2 and 4? Or for different reason?

Comment: Nevermind. It's 2*x^2*4 to make it dissapear when simplified to (a+c)^2.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^4+8x^2+16-9x^2=(x^2+4)^2-(3x)^2=$$
$$=(x^2-3x+4)(x^2+3x+4)$$

Comment: How did you arrive into this??? Can you please explain the procedure?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know what is the procedure. Please explain in detail.

Comment: For example $x^4+1=x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt2 x)^2=(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)$

Comment: @KKZiomek I have added a detailed answer below...

Comment: @AyanShah I have added a detailed answer below.

Comment: Thank you....i see that this process can be applied when the degree is even. Can you explain what procedure to follow when the degree is odd?

Comment: when the degree is odd we are looking for the root of the equation. If $\alpha - $ root of the equation $x^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$, then $x^3+bx^2+cx+d=(x-\alpha)(x^2+px+q)$

Comment: @AyanShah if you have any question pointed directly towards someone,use @ symbol and then add the user name...

Comment: @Roman83 .it was a great help to me, Thank you

Comment: and @tatan ..it was a great help

Comment: @AyanShah Nice to help you :-)...

Answer (score 3):

*Can be done by making perfect squares*
$$
Let\ ax^2 +bx + c=0
\\Try\ to\ make\ the\ equation\ look\ in\ the\ form
\\ax^2 +2\sqrt {ca}x +c-(2\sqrt{ca}-b)x=0
\\You\ will\ see\ that\ ax^2 +2\sqrt {ca}x +c\ makes\ a \ perfect\ square
\\\therefore \quad  ax^2 +2\sqrt {ca}x +c=(\sqrt ax + \sqrt c )^2
\\Thus\ the\ equation\ will\ convert\ to\ (\sqrt ax + \sqrt c )^2-(2\sqrt{ca}-b)x=0
\\Consider \ the\ term\ (2\sqrt{ca}-b)x
\\We\ can\ write\ it\ as\ {[\sqrt{(2\sqrt{ca}-b)x}]}^2
\\Thus\ the\ equation\ is\ converted\ to\ form\ p^2-q^2=0
\\where\ p=\sqrt ax + \sqrt c \quad and\quad q=\sqrt{(2\sqrt{ca}-b)x}
\\Equation\implies [\sqrt ax + \sqrt c]^2 - {[\sqrt{(2\sqrt{ca}-b)x}]}^2=0
$$
*Now you can apply* $p^2-q^2=(p+q)(p-q)$ *to get the required factorization.*

---

*Regarding your question
 Consider*
$$ a= 1,b=-1 ,c=16 \ and\ usual \ substitution\ x=x^2\ (both\ x\ are\ different)
\\ \therefore p=x^2+4 \quad q=3\sqrt {x^2}=3x 
$$

---

*After this its easy mathematics,you have to factorize 2 more easy equations thus giving you 4 roots.I hope , I did well to explain you :)*

Comment: ....thank you for your concern

Comment: No problem :) . Up vote if u found it useful :P

Comment: @JimmyKudo Consider using `\text{}` in math mode for more readable text

Comment: @michael Thanx for the suggestion, I was unaware of it.I will implement it from next answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Can be done by a simple completion of squares. The presence of $x^4$ and 16 hints towards a possibility of a $(x^2+4)^2$ so just calculate that and compare it with your question function. $(x^2+4)^2 = x^4+8x^2+16$ which leaves us with a difference only in the $x^2$ term. This difference turns out to be $9x^2$. So our function reduces to $$(x^2+4)^2-(3x)^2$$
It's easy to see after this, a simple use of $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ gives the final answer to be $$(x^2-3x+4)(x^2+3x+4)$$

Comment: By far the best answer here in my opinion,  at least for the level of knowledge the OP seems to have on this material. Not too simple in that you just show completing the square without pointing out why,  but not too complicated beyond the OP's level either.